# Как занести в таблицу данные, используя цикл SQL [Python]

Tags: python, mysql

Скорее всего это мега просто, но почему то реализация циклов в SQL поставила меня в ступор.

Есть вот такой код, суть в том что он уже работает, но надо как-то сделать так что бы все эти значения заносились циклом, а не мной вот так построчно.

```
order_list = "INSERT INTO orders(user_id,item_id) VALUES(%s, %s)"

val = [(1, 2),(1, 3)]

mycursor.executemany(order_list, val)

mydb.commit()
```

Comment: sql — это язык запросов. в этом языке просто нет циклов как явления. используйте циклы в языке python для формирования нужного вам sql-запроса. // конечно, ровно одним оператором insert можно добавлять и множество строк, но и это не цикл, это просто синтаксический сахар. и формировать текст этого оператора вам придётся всё-таки средствами python.

Comment: Вы в цикле заполните массив val а потом один раз вызовите executemany